# How can I launch app store from my application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, url, app-store, uiapplication

Im trying to implement button which opens app store application from my app. I use this simple line of code, which opens safari but not app store application.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://itunes.apple.com/sk/app/tweetie-2/id333903271?mt=8"]];
```

I dont know whats wrong, is the URL format correct? I was following [this document](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1629.html#TNTAG2).

All related questions in stackoverflow are outofdate I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bypass Safari, change 'itunes' in the URL to 'phobos'. Note that this will fail in the simulator, but most definitely works on the device.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, iTunes affiliate links have to process several redirects in order to wind up in iTunes. Follow the example to create an `NSURLConnection`, set yourself as its delegate, and use the string it ends up with to open with `UIApplication`.